# Xcode no longer starts after reboot

Tags: xcode, macos

After rebooting my mac, Xcode doesn't start.

I use Xcode 6.3 on OS X 10.10.2.

I click on the icon and nothing happens. I searched a while and found out how to start Xcode using the CLI.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

This works, but with following errors:

```
^[[Aobjc[2051]: Class IDEBlockScrollView is implemented in both /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Frameworks/IDEKit.framework/Versions/A/IDEKit and /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/PlugIns/IDEProductsUI.ideplugin/Contents/MacOS/IDEProductsUI. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
2015-06-19 10:47:29.245 Xcode[2051:80392]  DeveloperPortal: Using pre-existing current store at URL (file:///Users/admin/Library/Developer/Xcode/DeveloperPortal%206.3.db).
2015-06-19 10:47:29.319 Xcode[2051:80101] [MT] iPhoneSimulator: SimVerifier returned: Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=53 "Simulator verification failed." UserInfo=0x7fa3eee318d0 {NSLocalizedFailureReason=A connection to the simulator verification service could not be established., NSLocalizedRecoverySuggestion=Ensure that Xcode.app is installed on a volume with ownership enabled., NSLocalizedDescription=Simulator verification failed.}
```

How do I get Xcode repaired and to start with the icon again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When this happen to me, only this steps works :

- remove /Library/Developer
- remove Xcode.app
- restart your OS X
- download and re-install Xcode
- run Xcode

let me know if it's works?

Comment: is it fix your problem @Kevin?